# error when running firebase init functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm

After running the firebase init functions command line it is returning the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /home/ramon/apicloud/node_modules/protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command /home/ramon/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell -c -- node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/ramon/.npm/_logs/2024-01-25T02_16_00_381Z-debug-0.log
```

I already reinstalled npm and node and it still didn't solve the problem. Any suggestion?

*part of the Firebase Cloud Functions documentation that tells you how to start the project.*

To initialize your project:

Run firebase login to log in via the browser and authenticate the Firebase CLI.
Go to your Firebase project directory.

Run firebase init firestore. For this tutorial, you can accept the default values when prompted for Firestore rules and index files. If you haven't used Cloud Firestore in this project yet, you'll also need to select a starting mode and location for Firestore as described in Get started with Cloud Firestore.

Run **firebase init functions**. The CLI prompts you to choose an existing codebase or initialize and name a new one. When you're just getting started, a single codebase in the default location is adequate; later, as your implementation expands, you might want to organize functions in codebases.

The CLI gives you two options for language support:

JavaScript
TypeScript See Write Functions with TypeScript for more information.
For this tutorial, select JavaScript.

The CLI gives you an option to install dependencies with npm. It is safe to decline if you want to manage dependencies in another way, though if you do decline you'll need to run npm install before emulating or deploying your functions

---

the end of error stack with the error:

```
3116 verbose stack Error: command failed
3116 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
3116 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
3116 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
3116 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
3117 verbose pkgid protobufjs@7.2.6
3118 verbose cwd /home/ramon/apicloud
3119 verbose Linux 6.5.0-14-generic
3120 verbose node v18.5.0
3121 verbose npm  v8.19.4
3122 error code 2
3123 error path /home/ramon/apicloud/node_modules/protobufjs
3124 error command failed
3125 error command /home/ramon/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell -c -- node scripts/postinstall
3126 error /bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --
3127 verbose exit 2
3128 timing npm Completed in 51906ms
3129 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1706148960471
3130 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1706149011539
3131 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1706149011540
3132 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1706149011540
3133 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1706149011561
3134 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/protobufjs 1706149011561
3135 verbose code 2
3136 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
3136 error     /home/ramon/.npm/_logs/2024-01-25T02_16_00_381Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: so, what `firebase init functions command line` are you running?

Comment: the command is firebase init functions according to the firebase cloud functions documentation

Comment: is it too hard to write what you did? Which particular init command did you run to get that error? Also, what shell is your `/bin/sh` linked to?

Comment: @JaromandaX I used /usr/bin/dash. this is wrong?

Comment: no, I'm not saying anything is wrong, but `--` in `dash` does not have the same meaning as in `bash` for example - though, I would've thought since this elusive init procedure is using `/bin/sh` it'd be smart enough to figure out WHICH shell and act appropriately - but then, firebase is another crap product from the crap people at google, so who knows

Comment: I ran exactly the following commands in the project folder:
npm install -g firebase-tools // firebase login // firebase init firestore // firebase init functions > here returned the error. I believe it is something related to the installation of node dependencies but I'm not sure.

Comment: so `npm install -g firebase-tools` and `firebase login` and `firebase init firestore` worked, only `firebase init functions` failed? See, THATS the level of detail I was asking for

Comment: exactly dude! only this damn command failed. I added the error stack to the question body.

Comment: How well do you know linux? Try changing what `/bin/sh` points to

Comment: I'm not an experienced Linux user, I'm honest in saying this! to know where it points should I use the command ```readlink -f /bin/sh ``` ?

Comment: change it to `/usr/bin/bash` I guess - assuming you have `bash` (debian based you will but who knows with some other distros)